# API save new value and old value from the angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs

I want to build on functionality like I get old value and new value from the client side and my API will save both of the values in separate table. 
Exp: there is FirstName is aaa and LastName is bbb. User Change the FirstName ccc and LastName ddd. then when I update the same in main table and same time I want to update one table where I can save the values like old and New for the future purpose.
Please suggest me best way to do the same in API2

Answer (score 0):

don't think it is related to `angularjs` (more on `database` design) but anyway if you want to do this than one way would be to have a **new table** where you can save **firstname** and **lastname** along with **timestamp**. Most recent timestamp will correspond to the latest value.

### FirstName | LastName | TimeStamp

### aaa             | bbb           | 201603171015

### ccc             | ddd           | 201603171045

### xyz             | pqr            | 201603181135

This will be more like maintaining version history and there are many alternate ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Database point of view its fine but my question is how to get these values in API. When I got these values from the client(I'm using AngularJS) then easily I save them into database.

Comment: your client doesn't need to send old values. It is not the responsibility of client. Lets assume you have an API to update first and last name. When your client (`angularjs app`) calls this API with new values, your API should query DB (or cache) for existing values and then if name is changed it should log the old values

Comment: only for the one form its file but for all the website I don't think it's valuable . I want to make one Global Method which accept module name, key value pair and insert it. By doing this we shouldn't bother about all the modules store procedures. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: is there any way to use  IOrderedDictionary in WebAPI. ASP.Net we can use this to store values. my Method looks like below: 
Audit (string moduleName,  string moduleId, IOrderedDictionary OldValues, IOrderedDictionary NewValues)

Comment: I solve this issue. what I do, I am accepting two Dictionary array from the client and then compare there value based on key and value. if same key value matched then I'm not going to insert data into database otherwise calling inserting method to the DB.